# Is restoring PC to factory settings safe for a custom built PC?

Tags: desktop-computer, system-restore

I bought a new custom built PC from a guy and after about a year of use I want to know if restoring it to factory settings will make me have to set up or recalibrate the CPU, GPU, liquid cooling system etc.? Like will I have to find my Windows 10 DVD and reinstall Windows with the serial number etc.? This computer came without any restore points and it keeps deleting mine and turning off system restore.

Comment: You may need to reinstall drivers for the GPU and other devices, and you'll need to reinstall apps, but it should be safe. Your Windows 10 license [will remain intact thanks to a streamlined activation process](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440) and you should not have to reenter the product key.

Comment: I always suggest you ensure you have the Ethernet/network drivers on a separate device. As long as you can get internet access and the computer can read the storage where you saved the driver, you should have no problem. Since you have the DVD you should have no issues

Answer (score 1):

You have nothing to worry about. Like @bwDraco mentioned all you are going to have to do after the wipe is reinstall your drivers for everything (GPU, sound cards, WiFi cards, DVD drives, mice, keyboards, etc). You will essentially be going through the same process that installing a clean storage drive would entail.

Also on a side note, if you are going to clean install Windows and do not already have an SSD now would be a great time to upgrade to one.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing OS of your PC is safe, as long as you still have the drivers, there should be no problem. Windows will display all the applications removed into an internet explorer file that will be located on your desktop. You can view it if you are not sure what are the applications installed on your OS when it is still working.